# CSV ‘A$ 12,000.00’ from string to float with pandas and read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert a csv into a required format where a text field contains currency data in th format "A$ 1,000.00"

I can replace the "A$ " using: `df.Credit.str.replace('A$ ','',regex=False)` and then later convert the remaining string value to a float by casting it at the time of use, but I forgot the thousands are comma separated.

When importing the csv into the dataframe, I can use the thousands separator keyword, but because the column is imported as a string, it's not given a numeric value (because of the 'A$ ').

So I need to run the conversion of the comma AFTER importing it.

Is there a way I can do it all in the initial read of the CSV?

This is what I'd come up with so far, but doesn't work because it is out of order:

```
import pandas as pd

from collections import defaultdict

file = 'mydatafile.csv'  
data = pd.read\_csv(file,thousands=',')  
data.Credit = data.Credit.str.replace('A$ ','',regex=False)  

sales = defaultdict(float)  

for k,v in data.iterrows():  
sales[k]+=float(v.Credit)

print(dict(sales))
```

There are a couple of similar questions however they lack answers or don’t apply, eg:

[Pandas: Read CSV: ValueError: could not convert string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319011/pandas-read-csv-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float) 
I’m already using the thousands separator without success.

[Panda load csv string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880052/panda-load-csv-string-to-float)
Again, not the same, and the solution is unrelated to my problem

edit: I have also found this similar, but opposite question where someone is wanting to apply a format over the data, where-as I'd more like to remove it.

Can I somehow apply a `regex` that encompases both the removal of the `A$` and subsequent commas? Or is there a way to have the data be 'accepted' just in the way speadsheets 'ignore' currency symbols? I know this isn't a spreadsheet, but if pandas could be told that a string of this format is actually a float, that would solve my issue.

edit: for the time being, I have implemented Björn's answer with an extra `.str` to make it work, such that:

```
data.Credit = data.Credit.str.replace('A$ ','',regex=False).str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

complete code:

```
import pandas as pd

from collections import defaultdict

file = 'mydatafile.csv'  
data = pd.read\_csv(file,thousands=',')  
data.Credit = data.Credit.str.replace('A$ ','',regex=False).str.replace(',','').astype(float)

sales = defaultdict(float)  

for k,v in data.iterrows():  
sales[k]+=float(v.Credit)

print(dict(sales))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato)

Comment: Remove the Substring as you do and then use the `locale.atof` . i.e. like this `data.Credit.apply(locale.atof)`

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float)

Comment: Not really, I do know I can manually convert it myself and I could even pre-process the CSV file, however, I would like to do this in the import in one go because, a) I am doing this repeatedly, with different sets of data and b) the database is huge. I don’t really want to load it in, then iterate over it to change the format of it. I’m hoping to do it on import. *Edit: this comment was regarding the first comment. Thanks for other info. Checking them now.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom converter in `read.csv`:

```
...
import re
...
rx = re.compile(r'A\$\s*([0-9,.]+)')
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), converters= {'Credit': lambda x: float(
    rx.match(x).group(1).replace(',',''))})
```

This code expects the column to have a consistent format and does not care for formatting errors. If this is required, a full function with tests will have to be used.

---

If you only need to process lines where the field only contains NaN string and/or blank characters, you can filter them out with another regex:

```
rx = re.compile(r'A\$\s*([0-9,.]+)')
empty = re.compile(r'\s*(?:nan)?\s*$', re.I)
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), converters= {'Credit': (
    lambda x: np.nan if empty.match(x) else float(
    rx.match(x).group(1).replace(',','')))})
```

Comment: ahhh, `converters`, I did not know about this, it does sound like what I am after! The format is consistent(-ish) except that when there is a thousands separator, because it is a CSV, that field will be surrounded by quotes. I suspect that could be facilitated in the regex though. Thanks, this gives me a great place to start

Comment: as it turns out, a full function with tests is required. I just kept getting errors and digging deeper I found there are the occasional entries that are `NaN` or `' '` which just caused me endless worlds of pain.

Comment: @Madivad: If you only have empty fields or NaN, another regex could be enough

Answer (score 1):

So for visibility here one way to do it:

Remove the substring like you do with:

```
data.Credit = data.Credit.str.replace('A$ ','',regex=False)
```

Next use a combination of `locale` module and the `.apply` of pandas

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 
data.Credit.apply(locale.atof)
```

---

Another option would be to chain replace and convert via `astype`

```
data.Credit = data.Credit.str.replace('A$ ','',regex=False).replace(',','').astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that will do it. I’ll let you know when I get to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, as is it didn't work, I got the same `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,440.00'`, however, after adding another `.str` in there, it did work. It's ugly, but it gets the job done. I would love for a more elegant way to do this. Thanks again!